# Supplement form on the fly

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

**[SETTINGS]**

- Symfony 3.4
- Package entity : [id, form_id, maretial_id, design_id]
- Form entity : [id, form_name]
- Material entity : [id, material_name, form_id]
- Design entity : [id, design_name, material_id]

**[PROBLEM]**

I would like to know how to supplement a form with data from an Ajax request.

In my main form, I can select only select the `package form (form_id)`.
Once it's selected, via an Ajax request, I will look up for every material objects which are compatible with the selected `form`:

Form my controller, I'm calling my form builder :

<kbd>**FormMaterialsType.php**</kbd>

```
public function buildSupplementForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('material', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Material',
            'choice_label' => 'Material',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                          ->where('m.form= :form');
                          ->setParameters(array(
                              new Parameter('form', $options['form_id']),
                ))
            },
            'empty_data' => null,
            'required' => true)
        );
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a full form. How can I get only the `select` bloc?

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to choose a package from your select box and dynamically fill the data to your material select box right ?

Comment: Yes, once a `form` entity is selected for the package, I have to select the material, which will be added to the current HTML form

Comment: It a little bit tricky so I can give you only the steps but check the docs and you will be fine.After you be more familiar with this routine you will see the full power of it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need is [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

The main steps are:

- Listen for a change event on your package select box
- Submit the form from javascript
- In your FormType you need to add a subscriber and listen for a POST
  event on your form
- Inside your subscriber you must create the functionality so based on
  the selection in package to query for the right materials
- After all that is done in your javascript you load the new select box
  by replacing it with the new one

> Symfony Docs Example:

```
$("#material_select_box_id").replaceWith($(html).find('#material_select_box_id'));
```

So now your material select box will be loaded with the data from the subscriber

Comment: Thanks, I will try this asap